# Use regex inside Array.indexof in c#.net to find the index of element

Tags: c#, .net, regex

There is a list which adds the string at runtime.
The string in the list can be like

```
List<string> myList=new List<string>();
  0    7- 9
  1    3 - 6
  2    1 -3
  3    10-12
```

Here the string contain in list does not have same pattern.
Suppose I want to find the index of 3 - 6. 
So I have use an expression

```
3\s*\-\s*6
```

Now how to use it in Array.Indexof method so that I can get index of this element from mylist.

Comment: `List<string> myList = new List();` should be `List<string> myList = new List<string>();` shouldn't it?  And why Regex? Why not simply use `.Find()` or `.Contains()`?

Comment: .contains will not work because in advance I dont know what would be the pattern of string in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do

```
str.Replace(" ", "");
```

and then you get rid of whitespace

and can just do

```
str.IndexOf("3-6");
```

Comment: Calling `replace` on every element might imply creating a whole new list of strings... and _then_ doing a search.

Comment: @dcastro unless you insert it that way to the list. plus you don't have to create a new list. doing str.Replace(" ", "").IndexOf("3-6"); is possible...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think he's searching for a string in a list, not a substring in a string (which is what `str.Replace().IndexOf()` does)...

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
myList.FindIndex(s => new Regex(@"3\s*\-\s*6").Match(s).Success);
```

**Edit**: 
Working sample:

```
        List<string> myList = new List<string>
            {
                "7- 9",
                "3 - 6",
                "1 -3",
                "10-12"
            };
        int index = myList.FindIndex(s => new Regex(@"3\s*\-\s*6").Match(s).Success);


        Console.WriteLine(index); // 1
```

Comment: its giving error as   Expression cannot contain lambda expressions

Comment: Hmm is that a compile-time error? Can you tell me more about the error?

Comment: Also, forgot to put a `@` before the regular expression, ive edited my answer.

Comment: which line is throwing that error? the problem must be somewhere else in your code. I've tested this, and it works. Ive edited my answer and added a working sample.

Comment: I believe its QuickWatch showing that error, the code is fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var match = Regex.Match(String.Join(String.Empty, myList.ToArray()), @"3\s*\-\s*6");

if (match.Success) {
    // match.Index to get the index
    // match.Value to get the value
}
```

Comment: @Bidhu I have list and not yourstring

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same using LINQ:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"3\s*\-\s*6");
var index = myList.Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
                  .Where(x => regex.Match(x.x).Success)
                  .Select(x => x.i)
                  .First()
```